# Why the Source Package not getting identified when created using Android Test Project in Eclipse Helios

Tags: android, robotium

Am a QA engineer for the Android/IOS apps. As well as new to automation. I am trying out to automate some apps using Robotium. Referring to the link http://testdroid.com/tech/54/automated-ui-testing-android-applications-robotium

But when I created a new Android Application Test Project, the package is not getting identified and am not seeing any default classes inside it.

Attaching the snapshot. Can you folks plz help me as to why the package is not getting identified!!

The com.example.demo.qa.app.test is shown as null. Am wondering as to what is the reason for it.

Thanks[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to read the manual, in your own [example](http://testdroid.com/tech/54/automated-ui-testing-android-applications-robotium) or in [their web](http://code.google.com/p/robotium/) There are no default classes afaik, you have to create your test class in that package